# How can I perform a "find" function on a single HTML page with collapsable sections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a help page that has collapsable sections using twitter bootstrap. Here is a minimal code sample:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">

<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
      Sample heading one
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Sample paragraph one</p>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
      Sample heading two
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Sample paragraph two</p>
  </div>
</div>  

</div>
```

Rather than setting up a database, indexing the page, adding a search box, and creating a search results page; I would like to allow users to use a "find" function similar to the "find" functionality that comes with browsers, i.e. type a word, find the matching word, and move to the next word upon click.

Since my page is filled with collapsable sections, I would like the section to expand upon find. So my question is how can I perform a "find" function on a single HTML page with collapsable sections?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with the collapsible sections working?

Comment: Made it for you ..http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/yyLx12br/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be something of a programmatic hammer but it should do the trick:

#### Fully commented code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/yyLx12br/11/) if its not clear what's happening

```js
$('#find').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.prop("disabled",true); 
    var term = $('#term').val(); 
    $('.collapse').collapse("hide"); 
    var rd = new RegExp('<span class="found">('+term+')<\/span>', "ig");
    $('#accordion2').html( $('#accordion2').html().replace(rd, '$1' ) ); 
    var occurences=[]; 
    $('#accordion2 .panel-body').each(function(i,e){ 
        var r = new RegExp('('+term+')', "ig"); 
        if( $(this).html().match(r) ){ 
            var matches = $(this).html().match(r); 
            $.each(matches, function(){ 
                occurences.push(i); 
            });
            $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(r, '<span class="found">$1</span>') );  
        }
    });
    var l =occurences.length; 
    var c = Number( $('#current').html() ); 
        c =  c > 0 ? c+1: 0;  
        c =  c > l ? 1 : c; 
        c =  c == 0 && l > 0 ? 1 : c ; 
    $('#count').html( l > 0 ? ' of '+ l : ' matches found in document');  
    $('#current').html( c ); 
    if(c != 0){
        $('#accordion2 .accordion-toggle').eq( occurences[c-1] ).click(); 
        $('.found').eq(c-1).focus();
    }
    setTimeout(function() { btn.prop("disabled",false); }, 1000); 
});

// reset everything if the user starts typing again
$('#term').keydown(function(){
    var term = $('#term').val(); 
    var rd = new RegExp('<span class="found">('+term+')<\/span>', "ig"); 
    $('#accordion2').html( $('#accordion2').html().replace(rd, '$1' ) ); 
    $('#count').html(''); // reset our labels
    $('#current').html('');
});
```

```css
.found{
  background-color:yellow;
}
span{
    margin-left:15px;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="term" value="cool" placeholder="search.."/><input type="button" id="find" value="Find"/><div id="labels"><span id="current"></span><span id="count"></span></div>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">

<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
      Sample heading one
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Cool sample paragraph one</p>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
      Sample heading two
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Cool sample paragraph two</p>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
      Sample heading three
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Cool sample paragraph one</p>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour">
      Sample heading four
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Cool sample paragraph two cool</p>
  </div>
</div>  
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, you can use the `:contains(my_string)` pseudo-selector. Here is an example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/911d1zwk/

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    var search = $("input").val();
    $("div.collapse").find(":contains('"+search+"')").parent().collapse("show");
});
```

This takes your search string and finds which collapsible divs it exists in. This can be multiple divs. Then it triggers Bootstrap's "expand" method on the correct accordions. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try collapse() function in bootstrap to hide and show accordion. Here's a working example.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('a.searchContent').on('click', function(){
 var q = $('input#input_search').val();
 searchFunction(q.toLowerCase());
 });
 });
 
   function searchFunction(s){
  console.log(s);
 $('.collapse').each(function(){
   var divText = $(this).text();
   console.log(divText.toLowerCase(), s);
   if(divText.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) > -1){
  $(this).collapse('show'); 
   }
   if(divText.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) < -1){
  $(this).collapse('hide'); 
   }
 });
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">

<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
      Sample heading one 
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Sample paragraph one, Abc, xyz</p>
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
      Sample heading two
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Sample paragraph two, def, wxy</p>
  </div>
</div>  

</div>

<div><input type="text" name="search" id="input_search" /><br>
<a href="#" class="searchContent">Search!</a>
</div>
```